# Permission problems with Git sharedRepository

Tags: git, permissions, repository, gitolite

I am using Gitolite to manage my git repositories. And I also use a third-party web application to display the repositories.

However each time I do a `git push --all git@myserver.com:myproject` the third-party web application can not have access to the repository files. So I need to run each time `chmod go+rx -R /path/to/the/repository/folder` to see the repository.

I have set `git config core.sharedRepository all` but still is not remembering the permissions after `git push`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a [hook to your gitolite environment](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/admin.html) in order to update a non-bare pos (with the right ACL) from your bare repo managed by gitolite.

As long as you don't use **[the `update` hook](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks)** (in Gitolite V3), you can define an `post-receive` hook in which you would do those tasks.

That being said, check also if the [variable <del>`REPO_UMASK`</del> `UMASK`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html) in your gitolite.rc has any bearing on this issue:

> `$UMASK`, octal, default 0077
>
> The default `UMASK` that gitolite uses makes all the repos and their contents have `rwx------` permissions.
>   People who want to run `gitweb` realise that this will not do.
>   The correct way to deal with this is to change this variable to 0027 (which gets you `rwxr-x---`), then add the apache or httpd user running the webserver as a member of the 'gitolite' group.
>
> Please note the syntax; the leading 0 is required. If you change it after the install is complete, you'll have to do some `chmod`'s also to adjust permissions of files and directories that have already been created.

(Note: `REPO_MASK` got `UMASK` with [GitoliteV3 or 'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html))