# Auto deployment PHP script using Gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

i would like to setup auto deployment script to my testing server locally.
i'm using gitolite on ubuntu desktop 11.04.
i install gitolite using apt-get install gitolite, so it is create user gitolite and group gitolite.
Now i setup my testing webserver using apache which has user and group ivan:ivan,
and do git clone under that username.
so all the files and folder have the same file owner ivan:ivan.

i setup post-receive hooks under /var/lib/gitolite/repository/testrepo/hooks/ and have this script inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIG
LIVE="/home/ivan/public_html/testrepo"

read oldrev newrev refname
if [ $refname = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
  echo "===== DEPLOYING TO TEST SITE ====="
  unset GIT_DIR
  cd $LIVE
  git pull origin master:
  echo "===== DONE ====="
fi
```

Since post-receive hooks is executed by gitolite user, it has permission problem to access to the test server which is using user ivan.

i already add gitolite to ivan group and make it group access write, but still it cannot run.
i know this is a permission problem, but i don't know the solution.
If you have same experience or got any tips, i would really appreciate it.

Thanks
Ivan

Comment: What is the umask you have set for your gitolite repos? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086325/setting-umask-in-git-gitolite/7103499#7103499, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915482/gitolite-and-file-permissions/9915919#9915919, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455070/permission-problems-with-git-sharedrepository/5455127#5455127

Comment: hi VonC, i believe i still using default gitolite umask. but i think that doesn't matter. in my script up there, is executed by gitolite user in repository which is own by user ivan. So when it is doing pull, the gitolite cannot access the git ref head because of permission problem. Is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: try modifying the umask configured by Gitolite anyway, just to check if that changes anything.

Comment: Hi VonC, i still get this message: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied. Is there any samples or workaround to push "develop" branch to testing server, and "master" branch to live site using Gitolite. i already read Gitolite hook chaining but i can't understand it. I am still new with this Git. Thanks. Ivan.

Comment: hook chaining is only when you have several hook of the same type (like 'post-update', since Gitolite works with a post-update hook: if you have your own, you need to "chain" it in order for your own hook to be executed after the one set by Gitolite)

Comment: one example which mirror your own is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448682/git-submodule-on-remote-bare/9448794#9448794

Comment: Hi VonC, finally i got it working. i create another staging repository (bare=true), and i do mirroring from gitolite repository to that staging repo with git push in post-receive hooks. then from that staging, i update my development box with another hook. That's the best i can make for now. and thanks for your pointer i really appreaciate it.

Comment: Quite interesting. could you detail your setup in an answer below (and you can actually accept your own answer), for others to see if they face the same issue?

Comment: Yes i will make it shortly. thanks, VonC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the solution on my own, thanks for VonC for the pointers.
My solution may not beauty but yet work.

So here are the steps that work in my solution:

1. I create a bare repositories which will have the same user permission with the web application.
2. In Gitolite Repositories folder (in Ubuntu: /var/lib/gitolite/repositories), i create a post-receive hook which will mirror the the repository the bare repo that i just created. Code is:

   `#!/bin/bash

   echo '==== DO MIRROR ===='

   git push --mirror user@host:path/to/bare.git

   echo '==== DONE MIRROR ===='`
3. And in my web application, i will create a remote that connect to that bare repo.
4. Then i create a post-receive hook in the mirrored bare repo, that will ask the web application to pull from it. The code:

   `#!/bin/bash

    WORK_DIR="/home/ivan/public_html/test/testing"

    read oldrev newrev refname

    if [ $refname = "refs/heads/master" ]; then

     echo "===== DEPLOYING TO LIVE SITE ====="

     unset GIT_DIR

     cd $WORK_DIR

     git pull mirror-repo master

     echo "===== DONE ====="

    fi`
5. Don't forget to chmod +x for both post-receive.

As i said before, it may not beautiful but yet work, at least for my current situation.  The reason why i'm not just pull it from the gitolite repositories is because of user file permissions. In Ubuntu (install from apt-get), gitolite hold user and group, gitolite:gitolite. and my web application is under my home folder (i'm using suPHP) which have user and group ivan:ivan. 
So when i pushed to the gitolite repositories, it will run the bash script under gitolite user, which cannot access the .git folder under my home folder.

So yes, for those who have better solutions, i'm eager to hear from you.
Thanks hope my solution may help others.
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

After a long google search, i frustrated to implement this auto pull feature when any push occurs. But my own way works with 3 simple steps.

1. Add a status variable /var/lib/gitolite/stat/project

   ```
   vim /var/lib/gitolite/repositories/project.git/hooks/post-receive
   #!/bin/bash
   echo '==== DO MIRROR ===='
   echo '1'>/var/lib/gitolite/stat/project
   echo '==== DONE MIRROR ===='
   ```
2. Prepare a script privilege by root

   ```
   vim /var/lib/gitolite/stat/autopull.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   hstat=`cat /var/lib/gitolite/stat/project
   enter code here
   if [ "$hstat" == 1 ]; then
   cd /home/suphpuser/public_html_staging/project
   git pull
   chown -R suphpuser.suphpuser /home/suphpuser/public_html_staging/project
   echo '0'>/var/lib/gitolite/stat/project
   fi
   ```
3. Run a script

   ```
   /var/lib/gitolite/stat/autopull.sh
   ```

That's all :)