# Tracking Gitolite (common) hooks in Git

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

The only thing I found in Gitolite's [manual](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks) on hooks, was:

> If you want to add your own hook, it's easy as long as it's not the
>   'update' hook. Just add it to $HOME/.gitolite/hooks/common and run
>   gitolite setup.

However, I would also like to *track the changes* made to these hooks, with the possibility to revert to an older version if needed (auditing functionality is [cited](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/why.html) as one of the big advantages of using Gitolite). So, basically, I was expecting something like having to add a `hooks` folder in my gitolite-admin clone, and then pushing the hooks to the server (like you do with the config or adding a public key).

Does this make sense? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those hooks can be added in your `gitolite-admin` repo (`gitolite-admin/hooks/common`) and push back to the Gitolite server.
So they are versioned. (At least that was the case with Gitolite V2, I'll have to check with Gitolite V3)

---

It turns out, it does work, except the [OP Rijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/801042/rijk) reports:

> The problem was an error in my conf, that stopped the setup program.
>   Commented out that line, and the triggers are installed properly
>
> It was this line in my `gitolite.conf`:

```
config hooks.showrev = "git log -1 --name-status --format='%%h (%%ad) ------------------------------%%n%%n%%B' %s".
```

> Don't know why, but triggered the following error:

```
FATAL: bad value 'git log -1 --name-status --format='%%h (%%ad) ------------------------------%%n%%n%%B' %s'.
```

> Commented it out for now, will probably rewrite the `post-receive-email` script later on.

---

The OP [Rijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/801042/rijk)'s current solution:

> The solution I currently have for this on Gitolite v3 is to:
>
> - put things in **`gitolite-admin/local-code/hooks/common`**
> - and then on the server put a full-path symlink to the relevant items within **`$HOME/.gitolite/hooks/common`**.

Comment: Nope doesn't work. The hook *is* pushed to the server (ends up in `~/.gitolite/hooks/common`, although unexecutable), but it's not copied/linked to the repositories under Gitolite, not even after manually running `gitolite setup`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Rijk just to check, what version of gitolite are you using?

Comment: The latest (g3). I downloaded it this week.

Comment: Sorry, never mind! The problem was an error in my conf, that stopped the setup program. Commented out that line, and the triggers are installed properly. Thanks!

Comment: @Rijk Excellent. Glad I could help. Could you just comment on what line we should be mindful of in the conf file?

Comment: It was this line in my `gitolite.conf`: `config hooks.showrev = "git log -1 --name-status --format='%%h (%%ad) ------------------------------%%n%%n%%B' %s"`. Don't know why, but triggered the following error: `FATAL: bad value 'git log -1 --name-status --format='%%h (%%ad) ------------------------------%%n%%n%%B' %s'`. Commented it out for now, will probably rewrite the post-receive-email script later on.

Comment: @Rijk Thank you for this feedback. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I do have to manually make it executable each time after I push a new version of the hook. For some reason Gitolite doesn't do this.

Comment: @Rijk for chmod issue, check your UMASK value (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455070/permission-problems-with-git-sharedrepository/5455127#5455127) in case it has any bearing.

Comment: Can you please clarify where you actually ended up installing your custom hooks? I'm running Gitolite v3 and when I try adding gitolite-admin/hooks/common and push, Gitolite returns the error "remote: FATAL: no files/dirs called 'hooks' or 'logs' are allowed".

Comment: The solution I currently have for this on Gitolite v3 is to put things in gitolite-admin/local-code/hooks/common and then on the server put a full-path symlink to the relevant items within $HOME/.gitolite/hooks/common .

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the code in src/lib/Gitolite/Conf.pm, you'll notice that it prints out "bad value" if there is one of the UNSAFE_PATT strings in the value.

And UNSAFE_PATT looks like this (in src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm):
$UNSAFE_PATT = qr([`~#\$\&()|;<>]);

The issue is your use of parenthesis (and the simplistic parsing in gitolite.conf)

Comment: Ah.. Is there any way of escaping the parentheses?